# Crash on Logout Functionality in Facebook sdk3.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk

```
I am using facebook sdk 3.1 & FBloginview.So i want to perform logout functionality 
from other view controller..
 Here is my code,

-(void)logout
{
    AppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) 
    {
        [appdelegate closeSession];       
    }
    [appdelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
 }
```

in app delegate method,

```
- (void) closeSession
{
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

So in the `closeSession` method I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: This question is very unintellectual, seemingly you have put little to no effort into it...

Comment: Why am i getting crash...?

Answer (score 3):

On logout button click remove all keys stored in userdefault for facebook

```
- (void)fbDidLogout
{
  NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

  for (cookie in [storage cookies])
  {
      NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
      NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
      if(domainRange.length > 0)
      {
          [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
      }
   }
}
```

OR

Facebook class already includes the cookie removal in its invalidateSession function,

which is called in `[facebook logout];`

Comment: As well as FB app stores login information in NSUserDefaults it also stores login information in NSHTTPCookieStorage. so above code should work.

Comment: Thanks fo reply. ok i am using FBlogiview. So, i want to logout from another view controller. How can i achive this ?.